# Are extensions of @MainActor classes on the main actor?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, mainactor

If a class is on `@MainActor`:

```
@MainActor class MyClass : NSObject
{
}
```

does this put all its extensions on `@MainActor` as well?

```
extension MyClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. As [SE-0316 - Global actors](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md) says:

> A type declared with a global actor attribute propagates the attribute to all methods, properties, subscripts, and extensions of the type by default.

Comment: I was expecting this, but wasn't 100% sure.  Thanks for the reference; I'm going to read through.  Looks more thorough than TSPL.

Comment: Yeah, [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html) is an accessible introduction to the concepts, but the [Swift Evolution Proposals](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/tree/main/proposals) tend to outline a few more implementation and design considerations.